# Execute bat file with electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

Hello I'm creating an app with react and electron and I have a weird bug. My app have to execute a bat file so I use exec to launch the bat file with paramters like this

```
import { homedir } from 'os';
import * as path from 'path';
import { access, mkdir } from 'fs/promises';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import * as childProcess from 'child_process';

const exec = promisify(childProcess.exec);

const newProject = async (event: any, ...args: string[]): Promise<any> => {
  const home = homedir();
  const dir = path.join(home, '/work', args[0]);

  // create project directory
  try {
    await access(dir);
    return { ok: false, err: 'project already exist' };
  } catch (e) {
    await mkdir(dir, { recursive: true });
  }

  const scripts = path.join(__dirname, 'new-project.bat');
  // C:\Users\Isai\Documents\work\hercule\apollon\electron\handlers\new-project.bat
  try {
    await exec(`${scripts} ${dir} ${args[1]}`);
    return { ok: true, msg: 'folder successfully created' };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return { ok: true, err: "unable to create project's folder" };
  }
};

export default newProject;
```

when I do like this I get an error who said that it is not an internal or external command but if I mannualy enter the path of the bat file it work. So I replace the line :

```
await exec(`${scripts} ${dir} ${args[1]}`);
```

by

```
await exec(`C:\Users\Isai\Documents\work\hercule\apollon\electron\handlers\new-project.bat ${dir} ${args[1]}`);
```

It work perfectly. At the beginning I though I had the wrong path but they are the same. So I don't understant why it's doing that and I can't enter manually the path or it won't work on other machine

EDIT: I have forget to tell that a piece of the script is correctly executing because it create the folder at the good place but I get an error

Here is my bat file

```
@echo off
cd %1
git init
git checkout -b main
echo This project was created with Hercule>> readme.md
git add .
git commit -m "init commit"
git remote add origin %2
git push -u origin main
```

Here is the error

```
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Isai\Documents\work\hercule\apollon\build\electron\handlers\new-project.bat C:\Users\Isai\work\return-of-the-patato https://github.com/Eexy/return-of-the-patato.git
[2] 'C:\Users\Isai\Documents\work\hercule\apollon\build\electron\handlers\new-project.bat' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
[2] ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
[2]
[2]     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:317:12)
[2]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
[2]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
[2]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
[2]   killed: false,
[2]   code: 1,
[2]   signal: null,
[2]   cmd: 'C:\\Users\\Isai\\Documents\\work\\hercule\\apollon\\build\\electron\\handlers\\new-project.bat C:\\Users\\Isai\\work\\return-of-the-patato https://github.com/Eexy/return-of-the-patato.git',
[2]   stdout: '',
[2]   stderr: "'C:\\Users\\Isai\\Documents\\work\\hercule\\apollon\\build\\electron\\handlers\\new-project.bat' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne\r\n" +
[2]     'ou externe, un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes.\r\n'
[2] }
```

It is in french but it said that it is not a internal command

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also include the full Windows error message: What command is not found?

Comment: What is the error you get? can you console log `${scripts} ${dir} ${args[1]}`

Comment: Yes I just add it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the probrem when I compile for electron __dirname is equal to " C:\Users\Isai\Documents\work\hercule\apollon\build\electron\handlers\new-project.bat" and I didn't see the build folder which is explain why I was having a issue